# Error on JSP - syntax error of page template

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jstl

I am facing an error just on my machine in the first line of code.

Here is the piece of code where I get the error on Eclipse:

```
 <%-- tpl:insert page="/styles/template/picage_template.jtpl" --%><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<%@ page buffer="4096kb" autoFlush="false" %>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/TLDs/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic"%>
<%-- tpl:put name="redirectArea" --%>
```

And the error is Syntax Error of page template. This template is default for all the jsps.

I already unchecked HTML_SYNTAX_VALIDATOR, JSP FRAGMENTS, XML VALIDATOR and JSP SYNTAX VALIDATOR.

Comment: Is that the actual error message? In the Problems or Markers view, what is in the Type column for the message?

Comment: @nitind The type is 'Page Template Problem'.

Comment: Is there a Page Template specific validator?